# Windows 11, not reacting to user input

Tags: windows-11

all of a sudden, I see this behaviour on a Windows 11 machine:

About 20 or 30 seconds after a fresh restart, I can not start new software: When I click on an Icon in the tray, the software does not show up - except Explorer, which continues to work as normal. When I check in Task Manager, an entry for the software I just clicked shows up, but I can not switch to it.

In addition, even some Windows functions do not work anymore - i.e I can not shut down or restart from the menu, the menu opens, but the buttons are unfunctional. And CTRL+ALT+DEL does not work anymore, and even after hours, the machine does not show a lock screen, it simply remaind active.

Directly after the fresh boot, I can start software, but after said 20 seconds, I can not open any new software. However, everything that was opened until then continues to work fine.

I checked out Task Manager: The machine is idle. Neither CPU nor Memory seem to be used intensely.

Safe mode works fine.

I disabled everything in Autostart.
I did a system file repair - it did something, but did not tell me what, and the problem continues.

I checked out the system logs: After every boot, it continued a MASSIVE amount of errors due to SFI and DHCP services not started. I changed those from disabled to Auto, the error messages were gone from the logs, but the problem continues.
No more errors or criticals in the system logs now.

The user of the machine is rather inexperienced. They might have installed something naughty inadvertedly.
I‘m pretty sure, that the user did not advertedly disable NSI and DHCP services, and according to the system log, there were no errors in regards to those not beeing active before the problem occured.

Any ideas or suggestions of what to do or try, before doing a system reset?

Comment: Is there a security software installed in addition to Windows Defender? Does this happen when booting in Safe mode with Network?

Answer (score 0):

> I did a system file repair...  but .... the problem continues.
>
> They might have installed something naughty inadvertedly.

I have seen this (very similar).

Best approach to get going again is a System Reset. This time, keep just data.

From Task Manager, select Run New Task.  enter cmd.exe and check the box Run with Admin Credentials.

In the command window, enter systemreset

Then select Keep only Data.

Let that rebuild and reinstall Apps. This will reinstall most drivers as well. This will fix most (not all) problems.

The Windows User Profile will be retained with this approach. If there are still problems, back everything up and reinstall Windows 11.